# Stand Alone Java Compiler?

Tags: java

I have latest JDK 1.6 installed on my computer. Is there some way I can compile a program with Java 1.5 without removing my 1.6 installation for the new installation?

I searched a bit online and I couldn't find much information.

I think I might download 1.5 from the website and compile it using it's path to javac...

Are there any suggestions on what I should do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Won't `javac -target 1.5 -source 1.5` be enough?

Comment: *"Won't `javac -target 1.5 -source 1.5` be enough?"*  Nope.  You need to throw in a `-bootclasspath` option to the `javac` invocation, which in turn requires the `rt.jar` of the target version.

Answer (score 1):

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html

Look at the "Cross-Compilation Options" section

Answer (score 0):

You can do following

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_22\bin\javac
```